# How to properly loop and build pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, iteration

I am done with the logic for my Pyspark dataframe and now must apply different inputs and combine the results.

I am wondering if there is any performance benefit to creating a UDF and calling it multiple times, as opposed to looping through the values, as shown below.

```py
### res_schema definition ###

twr = []
twr.append((330,900,900,18900,1))
twr.append((480,900,1800,27000,2))
twr.append((660,900,3600,36000,4))
twr.append((1440,0,25200,43200,1))
twr.append((10080,0,86400,259200,1))

results = []

for tup in twr:
    I = tup[0]
    R = tup[1]
    SR = tup[2]
    SW = tup[3]
    NR = tup[4]

    res = spark.sql(
        """
        SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(offdate) OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(ondate AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL {0} MINUTES FOLLOWING
        ) AS ld, SUM(works) OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(ondate AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL {0} MINUTES FOLLOWING
        ) AS ws
         FROM lc
         """.format(I))

    for r in res:
        results.append(r)

    ### More logic ###

resdf = spark.createDataFrame(results, res_schema)
```

My additional logic is extensive but still entirely spark sql so I am not sure if my slow runtime is due to the queries or the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not ideal to convert DF to List and then convert it to DF again. As when convert DF to List you will use benefits of pyspark like handling huge volume of data and parallelism.

You should try to model you logic in terms of map,filter,reduce functions on DF instead for creating list and applying logic on list.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to **avoid UDF** for better performance, esp in Pyspark as it is going to spawn seperate python process.

Next, If you are going to get a column value from Row 'r', you can try inbuilt **collect_list** or **collect_set** functions.